# React Native in VS Code: add configuration for iOS Device to launch.json

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, configuration, visual-studio-code

I have a React Native project open in Visual Studio code, and Im trying to run the project on a physical connected iOS device. I successfully ran the app on the device directly from Xcode, but from Visual Studio Code I'm having issues. I believe I need to add a configuration for the device into launch.json. I have tried different entries in there but non seem to work. What is the proper way to add a configuration for a connected iOS device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I eventually had and managed to get it to install and launch on the connected device. The value for key `name` does not seem to uniquely identify a connected device. Its just the name that shows in Device Debug drop down.

```
    {
        "name": "My iPad",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "target": "device",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    },
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to target a specific device, this is how it´s done:

```
{
  "name": "iOS Device",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
  "type": "reactnative",
  "request": "launch",
  "platform": "ios",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "target": "device",
  "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react",
  "runArguments": [
    "--device",
    "DEVICE NAME"
  ],
}
```

So you need to set `"target": "device"` to tell the debugger to run on a device, and then you set the device name through `"runArguments"`.

Comment: You are a life saver. Basically for me it worked after I have added "target": "device"

Comment: yes. first we have to keep the launch.json in the root folder and then call the command : react-native run-ios --device "your device name"

Answer (score 3):

Try with `react-native run-ios --device "your device name"`

Device name you can find in xcode

You can add this in `package.json` also

```
{
    start:ios: "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-ios --device \"your device name\""
}
```

You may need to install `ios-deploy`

```
npm install -g ios-deploy
```

For vscode `launch.json` you can add these configuration `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-ios --device \"your device name\"` in `launch.json` too

### launch.json

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Run app",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-ios",
            "--device",
            "\"your device name\""
        ],
    }
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, Kishan. I've went with the default style for the configuration, got it to work, see my answer.