# How do you configure VSCode to run on an iPhone with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-code

I want to run a React Native app on an iPhone, not on the simulator, using VSCode.

I came across this past question but cannot get various things here, including the accepted answer to work.
[React Native in VS Code: add configuration for iOS Device to launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877653/react-native-in-vs-code-add-configuration-for-ios-device-to-launch-json)

The original launch.json which launches/runs the simulator is:

```
{
  "name": "Debug iOS",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "type": "reactnative",
  "request": "launch",
  "platform": "ios"
}
```

If I try augmenting that to be this:

> ```
> {
>   "name": "Debug iOS",
>   "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
>   "type": "reactnative",
>   "request": "launch",
>   "target": "device",
>   "runArguments": ["--device", "iPhone"],
>   "platform": "ios"
> }
> ```

(iPhone is the name of my connected device as showing in Xcode)

Or use the accepted answer verbatim:

> ```
> {
>     "name": "My iPad",
>     "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
>     "type": "reactnative",
>     "request": "launch",
>     "platform": "ios",
>     "target": "device",
>     "sourceMaps": true,
>     "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
> }
> ```

Then neither work, in both cases there is the same error:

> An error occurred while launching the application. Error while
> executing command
> '/Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/ReactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.bin/react-native
> run-ios --device iPhone --no-packager --verbose': Error while
> executing command
> '/Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/ReactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.bin/react-native
> run-ios --device iPhone --no-packager --verbose' (error code 101)
> (error code 303)

Anybody got this working and knows what the error/problem/fix is?